# How can I tell if a full-text index is being used?

Tags: sql-server, index, t-sql, full-text-search

It's possible to tell how much a rowstore index is used, but what about full-text?

I could find nothing in any GUI or DMV. [Even dbatools doesn't support it](https://docs.dbatools.io/Find-DbaDbUnusedIndex.html).

I've inherited a server that has a few full-text indexes and I have no idea if they're needed. This question is my attempt at getting the data needed to feel safe in dropping them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no DMV or similar to show full-text index usage. I did wonder whether sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats could be used (and found one result that suggested it could), but I don't think this works (more on that below).

One method that should work is using Query Store. If this is enabled (and capturing ALL queries), you can search stored plans that use Full-Text search functions and from this find the relevant tables/indexes.

Make sure Query Store is [enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16#Enabling) and capture mode is set to ALL:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name>
SET QUERY_STORE = ON
    (QUERY_CAPTURE_MODE = ALL)
```

As plans in query store are stored as text, you can query any hitting full-text indexes. Something like this will work:

```
SELECT qsqt.query_sql_text, qsq.object_id, CAST(qsp.query_plan AS XML)  
FROM sys.query_store_query AS qsq      
JOIN sys.query_store_query_text AS qsqt 
    ON qsqt.query_text_id = qsq.query_text_id     
JOIN sys.query_store_plan AS qsp 
    ON qsp.query_id = qsq.query_id   
WHERE qsp.query_plan LIKE '%fulltextmatch%'
```

(Adapted from: https://www.scarydba.com/2020/05/11/find-indexes-used-in-query-store/)

You can also leverage other aspects of query store, like what the performance overhead of the queries are.

There are of course drawbacks - if Query Store was not already enabled, you'll have to wait long enough for queries to appear in there and in a busy environment (especially with the capture mode set to ALL) you've got to make sure you don't lose data due to query cache flushes. Probably most importantly, you need to be sure that Full-Text isn't used occasionally for something very important (that one report that's run annually that is full of Full-Text searches that rely on indexes you dropped 11 months ago). Maybe you could periodically export query store results over time and analyse late (but that's getting beyond the scope of this question).

You can't prove the negative and be 100% sure that something is *never* used. How certain you can be of it depends a lot on the complexity of your environment and how well you know it (and your appetite for risk). A better way to be sure is to ask people in your organisation that use your database. This might not be possible in all cases, but devs/report writers etc. might be able to help - a non-technical solution but might be more effective.

If you don't mind unsolicited advice, why do you want to remove these indexes? The old adage of "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" can have value. What benefit do you seek to gain from removing them, versus the possible risk if they are needed but removed. I understand wanting to 'tidy-up' an inherited system, but I'd suggest there are easier, safer and potentially more valuable ways of doing this. I don't know your circumstances of course, but I'd suggest to only pursue this if you have think these indexes are actually causing problems.

**Using sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats**

An [old stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346326/sql-server-full-text-search-index-usage) suggested that this could be used to find the usage stats with sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats, joing to sys.fulltext_catalogs and sys.fulltext_indexes.  Any queries on those tables that hit the indexes will cause those counters to increase, not just full-text searches.

I tested this on AdventureWorks2019 with the Full-Text catalog and indexes already setup as default.

Using the dm_db_index_usage_stats query:

```
SELECT FTSC.name AS CatalogName, 
       T.name AS TableName, 
       C.name AS ColumnName, 
       FTSI.unique_index_id as FTindexID,
       FTSIU.index_id as DMVIndexID,
       FTSIU.user_scans, 
       FTSIU.user_seeks,
       FTSIU.last_user_scan
FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs AS FTSC 
JOIN sys.fulltext_indexes AS FTSI ON FTSC.fulltext_catalog_id = FTSI.fulltext_catalog_id
JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS FTSIU ON FTSI.object_id = FTSIU.object_id AND FTSI.unique_index_id = FTSIU.index_id
JOIN sys.tables AS T ON FTSI.object_id = T.object_id
JOIN sys.columns AS C ON FTSI.object_id = C.object_id 
    AND FTSI.unique_index_id = C.column_id
WHERE FTSIU.database_id = DB_ID()
```

Results from at start of dm_db_index_usage_stats testing:

```
CatalogName TableName   ColumnName  FTindexID   DMVIndexID  user_scans  user_seeks  last_user_scan
AW2016FullTextCatalog   JobCandidate    JobCandidateID  1   1   0   1   NULL
AW2016FullTextCatalog   ProductReview   ProductReviewID 1   1   0   1   NULL
```

Run a Full-Text query:

```
SELECT *  
FROM Production.ProductReview  
WHERE FREETEXT (Comments, 'Maybe do')  
GO
```

The dm_db_index_usage_stats query Results in user_scans increasing (as expected):

```
CatalogName TableName   ColumnName  FTindexID   DMVIndexID  user_scans  user_seeks  last_user_scan
AW2016FullTextCatalog   JobCandidate    JobCandidateID  1   1   0   1   NULL
AW2016FullTextCatalog   ProductReview   ProductReviewID 1   1   1   1   2024-01-15 18:37:44.537
```

But, a non Full-Text query:

```
SELECT Comments 
FROM Production.ProductReview  where rating >3
```

Also results in the dm_db_index_usage_stats query returning an increase to the scans for that index increasing:

```
CatalogName TableName   ColumnName  FTindexID   DMVIndexID  user_scans  user_seeks  last_user_scan
AW2016FullTextCatalog   JobCandidate    JobCandidateID  1   1   0   1   NULL
AW2016FullTextCatalog   ProductReview   ProductReviewID 1   1   2   1   2024-01-15 18:39:59.407
```

I played around more with this but didn't make any progress. Its possible there's still something in this that could be used, but I can't find it and as is from the [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346326/sql-server-full-text-search-index-usage) I don't think works.

Comment: This easily earns my +1, but I really hope that this isn't actually the best way to do it. If resorting to the likes of Query Store is necessary, then you might as well [go all-out and check every reference to the table](https://www.sommarskog.se/sqlutil/SearchCode.html).

Comment: Thanks and agreed - I'm keeping an eye on this one as I'd be interested in finding out a better way if someone else knows of one. I was hopeful that there would be someway with the index stats DMV but I couldn't get anywhere with that (although it did look like there was a way to begin with, I think it was spurious results). Checking everything that references it would be the most comprehensive way, but if you have a lot of apps connecting to your DB that might not be practical. Interesting one, this.

Comment: I'm afraid that I must disappoint you; Nobody has provided a better answer. Unless you fancy dropping a bigger bounty on this, I suspect we will never know.

Comment: What about [Audit Fulltext Event Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/event-classes/audit-fulltext-event-class?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: You will be interested in reading my answer. I wish that I could draw more attention to it in hopes of finding someone who can perfect the method, but I think I may be at a dead end.

Comment: It seems that `QUERY_CAPTURE_MODE = ALL` and full-text indexes [don't play nice with eachother](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/337501/in-the-past-week-select-statman-has-run-150-000-times-is-this-normal). The index maintenance fires so many ad-hoc queries at Query Store that it can enter ready only mode.

Answer (score 0):

### Extended Events Can Do It... Badly

I've hunted for any Extended Event that fires when a full-text index is hit. I have only found two.

#### fulltext_query_exec_stats

`fulltext_query_exec_stats` seemingly fires whenever any full-text index is hit, no matter what. However, the only valuable information contained within its output is your search term. It tells you nothing about the index or table that was searched, **not even the name**.

If `fulltext_query_exec_stats` fires, then you know that a full-text index is being hit but not which (unless you can guess it from the search term or only have one full-text index in the entire server). That means that if it never fires, then you know for certain that no full-text index has been hit while you have been tracking the events.

#### fulltext_query_recompile

`fulltext_query_recompile` fires seemingly at random, but outputs the `database_id`, `object_id`, and `table_id`. This is enough to figure out what index was hit.

If `fulltext_query_recompile` fires then you know for certain that a particular index is being hit. I suppose that if you're only interested in one full-text index, then filtering for the `table_id` in question would be sure proof that your table's full-text index is being hit. However, **not seeing this event is not proof that your full-text index is not being used.**