# In the past week, SELECT StatMan [...] has run 150,000 times. Is this normal?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, full-text-search, statistics, monitoring

I retain a week's worth of Query Store data. I was inspecting it for one database earlier today and found something surprising. This query

```sql
SELECT *
FROM sys.query_store_query AS qsq 
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query_text AS qsqt
ON qsq.query_text_id= qsqt.query_text_id 
WHERE query_sql_text like 'SELECT StatMan%'
```

returned 150,000 rows. The results are all very similar to the queries mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246984/how-to-avoid-the-sql-servers-rebuild-statistics-when-doing-performance-testin). For example, one was like this

```sql
SELECT StatMan([SC0]) FROM
(SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT [keyword] AS [SC0] FROM [sys].[long_table_name_fragment_12345678_12345678]
WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ORDER BY [SC0]) AS _MS_UPDSTATS_TBL OPTION(MAXDOP 4)
```

and another is just like this, but with four columns.

This give me three questions:

1. What are these queries? They are obviously related to updating statistics, but how?
2. Is the frequency I've experienced normal?  **They seem to run every few milliseconds with different digits in the table names**.
3. Does anything about this suggest that my SQL Server is badly configured?

My statistics-related settings are as follows.

- Auto Create Incremental Statistics: False
- Auto Create Statistics: True
- Auto Update Statistics: True
- Auto Update Statistics Asynchronously: False

The comments have suggested that the maintenance of full-text indexes is to blame. As far as I can tell, this is correct. I find this issue in every database that has full-text enabled. Even though one of the databases' only full-text indexes is queried at most *twice a week* ([according to this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/334802/how-can-i-tell-if-a-full-text-index-is-being-used)), it has already has 40,000 queries that are `LIKE 'SELECT StatMan%` in the past two days.

In the GUI, I can change the following relevant-looking full-text index settings:

- Change Tracking: Automatic
- Repopulate Index: Not Ticked, but "Full" is selected under this.

Comment: Most likely because you have one or more databases with "auto" statistics options set (eg. auto-create, auto-update).  Provided you don't believe these things are causing any kind of issues, then it's just SQL doing its job

Comment: @Craig Where can I read more about this and the `_fragment` tables?

Comment: It looks like stats updates to full text indexes to me, judging by the "keyword" column. I'm not sure how much documentation you'll find on the fragment tables, since they're internal objects. Asking whether this is normal isn't really an answerable question. If you asked if using full text indexes is normal, it would be easy enough to say no.

Comment: @ErikDarling Very interesting. Any ideas on what causes statistics on full-text indexes to update? That would give me a way to ask if this is normal.

Comment: No, I've avoided everything about them for my entire career.

Comment: @ErikDarling Woe is me! We share the same goal, but I've inherited a database that's forced me down this path. Thank you for the sincerely entertaining comment. You've made me smile on a dark day.

Comment: @ErikDarling I've updated the question. You appear to be correct. I was surprised to find that I couldn't replicate the Query Store query in [this relevant answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/334887/277982) with your `sp_QuickieStore`. it's usually much better than querying the Query Store views. Do I lack skill or is it really not possible?

Comment: @J.Mini it [intentionally excludes](https://github.com/erikdarlingdata/DarlingData/blob/main/sp_QuickieStore/sp_QuickieStore.sql#L4079) them.

Comment: @ErikDarling Oh. Nice. I was thinking about the more general method of searching the plan's text like the answer does (I don't think that `sp_QuickieStore` supports that), but what you've done is cool.

Comment: @J.Mini No, it does. You should try using the help parameter.